How do I remove the iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation constraint
I am trying to implement backups for a Google Workspace using Synology's Backup for Google Workspace, and following their implementation guide.
I have set up a Project and am now trying to create a Service Account Key, but am unable to as there is a constraint enforced, namely iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation. There is a link in the error message which seems designed to take me to a page where I can disable the constraint, but clicking the link takes me to a 404 page.
It seems from reading the docs, that restricting Service Account Creation was introduced as a default on 3 May. While I understand the restriction, there needs to be a way of disabling the restriction, so that a Service Account Key can be created when needed.
As the creator and thus Super Admin of the Workspace, I do not appear to have the permissions required to disable the policy. Nor can I find any way to acquire these permissions.
Does anybody know how to acquire the permissions to disable the policy, or how to otherwise disable the policy.
Once the service account key is created, the policy can presumably be reinstated.
Google Workspace support has advised that they cannot deal with it, as it is managed within GCP, and I have therefor been referred to GCP support. However, as this is for a Not-For Profit charity, I have a free tier for Google Workspace, and thus limited support, and more importantly only basic support for GCP.
I have reviewed and/or followed instructions on the following pages:

The initial Synology How To page
GCP Documentation - Restricting service account usage 
GCP Documentation - Creating and managing organization policies 

The last link above suggests that I need the Organisation Policy Administrator role. However, as owner and Super Admin I apparently do not have this role, nor do I seem to be able to grant it to myself.
Does anyone know how to proceed here?

Did you create the GCP organization? If so, you have all the permissions on it. If not, and you are a Workspace super admin, you can try to go the the IAM service page and select the root organization in the project picker. Normally, if the org has been created by default, you, as Workspace admin, is also a GCP admin to grant you permission at the org level

@guillaumeblaquiere I did not create the organisation, so I presume that there is just a default Organisation. If I click on the IAM & Admin > Identity and Organisation it says that the page is not available for Projects. If I click on IAM & Admin > Organisation Policies - it shows a list of policies for the Project. I created the Workspace, and I created the Policy and set myself as Owner of the Policy.

Identity and organisation is not available at project level. Go on the upper left corner of the page and use the project picker. There click on the ALL tab (in the opened popup) and select your organisation root). Then, you will be at the root of your org and you will be able to do things.

@guillaumeblaquiere OK. I have now got to the point where I am now seeing a list of policies for the project that I created, and I also see that it is part of the organisation 'wells-community-shed.uk', which is the domain of the workspace that I created.
Therein, I can filter to find the policy "Disable Service Account Key Creation", and if i View it I can see that it is Enforced. I understand this constraint are now enforced by default, since 3 May.
If I try to edit the constraint, I get a message saying that I need a bunch of permissions.

Go to the IAM page, and try to grant your user the required role (look for organization admin)

@guillaumeblaquiere My user already has the Organisation Admin and Owner roles.

Strange... Are you log in with the correct user account?

@guillaumeblaquiere Yes. The account is the same email address for both GCP and the admin account of the Workspace.

If you have the Organization Admin role (roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin), then you can grant the Organization policy administrator role (roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin) to yourself in the IAM.
Then, you will be able to remove the iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation constraint.

The problem for me was I was looking in the IAM part for my project. That role (policyAdmin) only exists at the organization level (change to your org in the project dropdown at the top and it should let you add that permission to you and then let you edit policies).
